# How to make a random, reverse acronym (Backronym) in Python from a given list?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, arraylist, acronym

Suppose we have a name:
**x='STAR'**

and a list:
**y=['super', 'sunny', 'talented', 'arrogant', 'apple', 'razor', 'rhyme']**

How do we get an output like this -

**S for Super

T for Talented

A for Apple

R for razor**

*where all the words are picked up randomly from list y.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `list` and `dict`:

given an example :

`y=['super', 'sunny', 'talented', 'arrogant', 'apple', 'razor', 'rhyme']`

```
x = ''.join(list(dict.fromkeys(x[0].upper() for x in y)))
print(x)
>>> STAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

```
from random import choice
x = "STAR"
y=['super', 'sunny', 'talented', 'arrogant', 'apple', 'razor', 'rhyme']

t = ""
for c in x:
    y_filtered = [i for i in y if i[0].lower() == c.lower()]
    t += f"{c.upper()} for {choice(y_filtered)} "
print(t.strip())
# 'S for sunny T for talented A for arrogant R for rhyme'
```